# Example of decreasing sequence of sets with first set having infinite measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, lebesgue-measure

I was wondering if someone could please give me an example of a sequence of decreasing sets where the first set has infinite Lebesgue measure; i.e., $\{B_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $m(B_{1}) = \infty$ but $m(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_{n}) \neq \lim_{n \to \infty}m(B_{n})$?

thank you.

Comment: By "decreasing" do you mean that the measure decreases, or that $A_{n+1} \subset A_n \forall n$?

Comment: @Paul, I mean the sets  are nested.

Comment: Take $B_1 = \mathbb R,$ $B_n= (0,1/n), n > 1.$

Comment: $B_1 = [0,\infty), B_n = \emptyset, n>1$.

Comment: Are you taking the measure of the limit of the sequence of sets, or the limit of the measures?

Comment: @Paul, I fixed the question.  Just to clarify:  I need an example where $ m ( \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_{n} ) \neq \lim_{n \to \infty} m(B_{n})$ because $m(B_{1}) = \infty $

Comment: If any of the sets has finite measure, the measure of the intersection is the limit of the measures. So you need a sequence of nested sets with infinite measure such that the intersection has finite measure (for example, it may be empty).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $$B_n := \{x \in \mathbb{R}; |x| \geq n\}.$$

Comment: @JessyCat Actually, this is more or less already a complete answer. Just calculate $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} B_n$ and $m(B_n)$ - that's all.

Comment: sorry but what is $m(B_{n})$?

Comment: Hint:  $m(B_n)$ is really big!  Oops.  Just got scratched by Jessy Cat.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson, ha. ha. ha. Anyway, I figured it out not soon after and realized what a stupid question that was. It's all good.