# a decreasing sequence of sets with $\mu(A_1)=\infty$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(A_n)$ be a decreasing sequence of sets. I am looking for an example that if $\mu^*(A_1) = \infty$, $$\mu^*(\cap_{n \in N} A_n)\not= \lim_{n\to \infty}\mu^*(A_n).$$

I saw from another [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492847/example-of-decreasing-sequence-of-sets-with-first-set-having-infinite-measure) that if we define sets to be $A_1 = [0, \infty)$ and $A_n =\emptyset$ for $n \ge 2$, this sequence of sets can be an example which satisfies the above conditions. But, I do not understand why.

I think that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu^*(A_n)= 0$ as $A_n$ is empty set for $n \ge 2$. But, I also think that  $\cap_{n \in N} A_n = \emptyset$. That is, $\mu^*(\cap_{n \in N} A_n)=0$ as well.

Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: You have a solution here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492847/example-of-decreasing-sequence-of-sets-with-first-set-having-infinite-measure. You have seen an example in a comment by @copper.hat in a question that has been editted after the comment was written. Obviously the example doesn't solve the question as it is. But, do you know what the original question was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic example along these lines is $$ A_n = [n,\infty).$$ Note that each set has $\mu(A_n)=\infty,$ so $\lim_n \mu(A_n) = \infty$ but $\bigcap_n A_n = \emptyset.$

However, if the $A_n$ are decreasing and *any* of them have finite measure, then continuity holds.

I think copper.hat's example in the comments of the post you link refer to an earlier edit that didn't make clear that they were looking for an example with $\lim_n \mu(A_n) \ne \mu(\bigcap_n A_n).$

Comment: Oh.. Okay. Anyway, thanks.