# Show that $\mu(\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}F_{n})=\lim\mu(F_{n})$ can fail if $\mu(F_1) = +\infty$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Show that lemma 3.4 (b) in *The Elements of Integration* by Bartle may fail if the finiteness condition $\mu(F_{1})<+\infty$ is dropped.

> Lemma 3.4(b): Let $\mu$ be a measure defined on a $\sigma$-algebra $X$.  If $(F_{n})$ is decreasing sequence in $X$ and if $\mu(F_{1})<+\infty$, then
>   $$\mu \Bigg(\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}F_{n}\Bigg)=\lim\mu(F_{n})$$

Comment: I think there should be an intersection there...

Comment: Hello Max, here in math exchange you should explain more what thoughts did you have until here and try to show what you have done yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example of decreasing sequence of sets with first set having infinite measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492847/example-of-decreasing-sequence-of-sets-with-first-set-having-infinite-measure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that in the proof of Lema 3.4(b) when he defines the sequence of sets $E_n=F_1 - F_n $ , you can't say that $\mu (E_n) = \mu (F_1) - \mu (F_n)$ if $\mu(F_1)$ is not finite.

This could get you in trouble because expression like $\infty - \infty$ aren't well defined in this context.

For a counter-example, you could use $X=\mathbb{R}$ as the set; the power set $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ as the $\sigma$-álgebra and the following measure:

$$\mu (E)=\begin{cases} \vert E \vert \mbox{, if $E$ is finite}\\
+\infty\mbox{, otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Then use the sequence $F_n=(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$.

$\mu(\bigcap\limits _{n=1}^{\infty}F_n)=\mu (\{0\})=1  $, but $\lim\mu(F_n)=+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you sou much

Comment: Not begging for upvote but if you are already satisfied with the answers here you can mark the answer as correct and upvote it if you want to...

Comment: You're welcome! Hope you enjoy math stackexchange!

Answer (score 1):

As Robson said, please include your thoughts on the question. You'll get better responses if we know what you are thinking already.

However, I thought the question was interesting, so:

Hint: Can any of the sets have finite measure if the lemma is to fail?